# "Natural" sorting for ElementCriteria

Tags: elementcriteriamodel, sorting

I want something sorted like this:

- MyString8
- MyString9
- MyString10
- MyString11

`$criteria->order = 'myField asc` doesn't get things quite right, as MySQL has not native "natural sorting".

Answer (score 2):

You can fake it by first sorting by character length, and then by the value: `$criteria->order = 'CHAR_LENGTH(myField) asc, myField asc`

Its not perfect, but in certain cases, it will be all you need. Other methods exist as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8557307/935398

Note: `CHAR_LENGTH` is a MySQL function that is getting passed directly to the `ORDER BY` clause. It has nothing to do with Craft directly.